# Rails 3 Toolbar render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, render

In my website toolbar's I would like to display the number of unread messages in a red circle,

So I think the best way is to create a method in ApplicationController named update_notification :

```
  def update_notification
     @notification = 42 
     # 42 is just for test
  end
```

and in application.html.erb, I display :

```
<%= render :partial => 'messages/notification' %>
```

_notification.html.erb :

```
<div id="notification">
   <%= @notification %>
</div>
```

the problem is where and when can I call update_notification method (in ApplicationController ?) and do you think it's the best way to do it like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `periodically_call_remote`:

```
<%= periodically_call_remote(:url => { :action => 'update_notification' }) %>
```

And your action should use rjs to update the element on the page.

Create an rjs file (e.g. `update_notification.rjs`) with the following content:

```
page.replace_html "notification", :partial => "messages/notification"
```

and in your controller render it:

```
render :action => "update_notification.rjs"
```

Comment: Thanks :)
I think it's the best way

Comment: how can I call the rjs containing "page.replace_html" from update_notification method ?

Answer (score 0):

`before_filter` is what you are looking for. Add this to your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :update_notification
```

and your method will be called before every action.